# Flow: Stop deleting using delete trigger

Tags: visual-workflow, delete

I want to add a `before delete` trigger on a custom object so that no one can delete any record of this object.

I know I can do this in Apex by calling `addError()`, I was wondering if I achieve the same goal by using `Flow`.

Thanks

P.S. I can do it by not giving the `delete` priviledge in `profiles` as well. I am particular interest in if `Flow` can do the job in this question.

Comment: I believe not. Not yet at least. Read [this blog post](https://jenwlee.com/2020/09/28/winter-21-introducing-the-before-delete-record-triggered-flow/) about current capabilities.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks. Your comment really helped.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this with flow. Create a new field on whatever object you want to prevent a record from being deleted - I usually call this field "Do Not Delete". Then, create a Before Delete flow - all the flow needs to do is update the Do Not Delete field to true. You can introduce any other criteria as well, but the final step must be to update the Do Not Delete field to true. Finally, create a validation rule that throws an error if Do Not Delete is true. This will prevent your record from being deleted.

The validation rule actually triggers the flow to fail, so the record doesn't get deleted. The error message presented isn't the prettiest - I'm still trying to find a way to better present it - but the goal is accomplished.

Comment: You cannot fire `Validation Rule` on delete event.

Comment: You're not firing the validation rule on the delete event - you're firing it prior to the delete so the delete event - the Before Delete flow - fails and stops the delete entirely.

Comment: Indeed this works, thanks @MattB. The error message isn't the prettiest as you say, have you found a way to improve it with latest versions of Flow?